# SVN certificate problems

Tags: svn, certificate, verification

I've got a major problem with OSX and SVN. I'm using SCPlugin for accessing my SVN and I tried to checkout my data on my MacBook Pro. The SCPlugin told me when accessing the SVN url that the server certificate verification failed, because the issuer is not trusted.
On my iMac I just opened the terminal window and accessed the svn url by using:

svn ls https://my.svn.url

and the terminal asked me if I want to accept the server certificate. But my MacBook did not ask that question and I am available to access the svn via terminal but NOT via SCPlugin.

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this problem? I really would need help.

I need a way to accept the server certificate permanently!

Answer (score 0):

The `svn` command default to `/usr/bin/svn`, which was changed by Apple so it doesn't quite work the same, and cannot achieve this. Using `/usr/local/bin/svn` instead should solve the issue, i.e.

```
/usr/local/bin/svn ls <url>
```